# SCCM Device Collection Membership based on Machine Variable

Tags: sccm

I'm not sure if this is quite possible but I'm struggling with writing the WQL query statement that would allow me to have SCCM device collections populate based on a machine variable.

Example:
Device named "TestVM-01" has a machine variable named "PatchGroup" with a value of "Hour1".
I would like the device collection called "Hour1" to dynamically populate any devices with the PatchGroup variable set to Hour1.

I first struggled with just querying the device variables via powershell and WMI since the SMS_MachineVarible class is a lazy property of SMS_MachineSettings so you have to call the objects by their full path.

In Powershell/WMI I can query it with something like this

```
(([wmi]"\\SCCM-LAB\root\sms\site_001:SMS_Machinesettings.ResourceID=11111111").machinevariables | where name -eq "PatchGroup").value
```

If you query SMS_MachineSettings without specifying the full path of the object, it will return the MachineVariables attribute as empty

Would anyone be able to tell me how I would write the WQL for that to pull those list of objects from the SMS_Resource class "where PatchGroup = x"?

Comment: are you talking about a machine's environment variable?

Comment: The custom variables you can add on the Variables tab of a device

Answer (score 0):

A single WMI Query will not work on this, neither do the default 'Create Device Collection Wizard'. The lazy Properties is a list of another object instances' properties and values, we need to use SwbemServices.ExecQuery() COM interface in VBscript & PowerShell, or Get-WmiObject in PowerShell to pulling data.

I would do this using, like PowerShell Script, to generate a list of computer ResourceIDs and using these IDs to create a DirectRule collection using built-in CM cmdlet. Each time I will run the script before I'm going to use this collection.

See below script blocks to get list of ResourceIDs:

```
$cmdletLocaltion = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminConsole\bin\ConfigurationManager.psd1'
$sitecode = 'P01:'
Import-Module $cmdletLocaltion
cd $sitecode
#-Lines to cleanup all the directcollection membership rules -#
$machineObject = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\sms\site_p01 -Class sms_machinesettings
Foreach ($machine in $machineObject)
    {
        $Path = $machine.__PATH
        $machine = [wmi]"$path"
        foreach ($varvalue in $machine.MachineVariables)
            {
                if (($varvalue.name -eq 'PatchGroup') -and ($varvalue.Value -eq 'Hour1'))
                    {
                        $machine.ResourceID
                #--line here to add to collection membership--#
                    }
            }    
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that.  I would have liked to use the built in device collection membership because then I wouldn't have to remediate any memberships that have changed to keep servers in just one patch group collection  (ie: if a servers patch hour changes, remove it from hour1 AND put it in hour2)
If I have to do it in powershell as a scheduled task I would just use Get-CMDeviceVariable rather than querying WMI but that still makes me have to re-assess every patch group collections membership every time.